# View border shadow without affect its child

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to add a shadow to the border of my view . But, i dont want all the child in the view to be affected by the shadow too . I just want shadow outside the border of view , but not the text or image in the view . is it possible to do this ?

```
        <View style ={{
            margin:5,
            borderWidth:0.5,
            borderColor:'grey',
            borderRadius:15,
            overflow:'hidden',
            elevation:10,
            height:100}}

            ></View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for shadow :

```
view: {
    height : 100,
    width : 100,
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 0
    }
  }
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: hi , it doesnt work . the shadow still affect the text in the view

Comment: Okay. 
So can you please use 3rd party for your requirement?
[react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a shadow to the border of my view

You can apply the property `boxShadow` to your `<View>` element.

e.g.

```
boxShadow: '6px 6px 4px rgb(127, 127, 127)',
```